# Error while running jar that uses adb path while executing

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have written a java code which internally kicks of a process to launch an avd and gets hold of that process. I have tested the code on local windows 7 as well as ubuntu 11.04. On both of these local environment it works fine.

When I uploaded the same jar file on my aws instance, i get the following error :
12:30:38 E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

though /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb exists.

I have gone through bunch of similar questions but none of them have discussed this issue.

I have updated my openJDK as some of the sites suggest but still i face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

on Linux system if you want to execute any executable then prefix **"./"**

like this in your case

```
cd /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/
```

then `"./adb"`

Comment: `/the/path/to/your/executable` and `cd /the/path/to/your/` followed by `./executable` are the same thing. The dot is shorthand for the current directory, `./executable` is the same as typing the full path. Both work.

Comment: sometimes its not working in Ubuntu, you have to navigate to the directory(contains executable) and then execute "./executableName"

Comment: as alextsc saying it means the same but i tried both... both of them gifts me the same error :(

Comment: and i cant navigate as inside code i call Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb <some operation>");

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to 32 bit libs.
My aws ubuntu os was 64 bit and my jar was compiled for 32 bit architecture, so i had to install ia32-libs and everything started working fine.